# how to pass boolean as props

Tags: reactjs, boolean, react-loading-skeleton

I'm trying to implement skeleton on my components, I'm using boolean to set if the components are loaded completely or not

**`Post.jsx`** (I guess here where the skeleton should show)

```
import Skeleton, { SkeletonTheme } from 'react-loading-skeleton'
import 'react-loading-skeleton/dist/skeleton.css'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export default function Post({ post, isPostsLoading }) {
  moment.locale('ar');
  const daysAgo = moment(post.createdAt);

  const rowSkeletons = 6
  const GalleryStyles = styled.div`
    .gallery__grid {
        display: grid;
        gap: 2rem;
        grid-auto-flow: dense;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(100%, 260px), 1fr));
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .gallery__title {
        font-size: 2rem;
        padding: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
    }`
  if (isPostsLoading) {
    let rows = []
    for (let index = 0; index < rowSkeletons; index++) {
        rows.push(
            <section>
                <article className='item'>
                    <div className='item-img'>
                        <Skeleton width={140} height={140} />
                    </div>
                    <h3 className='item-title'><Skeleton count={4} /></h3>
                    <div className='item-info'>
                        <Skeleton width={160} height={20} />
                        <Skeleton width={30} height={20} />
                        <Skeleton width={22} height={22} circle={true} />
                    </div>
                    <Skeleton height={48} count={2} className='skeleton' />
                </article>
            </section>
        )
    }
    return (
        <SkeletonTheme color='#F5F5F5' highlightColor='#ffffff'>
            <GalleryStyles className='gallery__grid'>
                <h2 className='gallery__title'><Skeleton /></h2>
                <div className='gallery__grid'>
                    {rows}
                </div>
            </GalleryStyles>
        </SkeletonTheme>
    )
}
  return (
    <div className="post">
        <div>
        {post.photo && (
        <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} className="link">
        <img
        className="postImg" 
        src={post.photo} 
        alt="" 
        />
        </Link>
        )}
        </div>
      <div className="postInfo">
        <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} 
            className="link">
            <span className="postTitle">
              {post.title}
            </span>
        </Link>
        <div> 
            <p dir="auto" className="postDesc">
              {post.content}
            </p>
        </div>
            <span className="postDate">
              {daysAgo.fromNow()}
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want each div shows a skeleton till i'ts fully loaded.

**`Posts.jsx`** (Here where an array of posts are showing)

```
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';

export default function Posts({ posts = [], isPostsLoading}) {
    const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState([]);
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
// HERE isLoading is for search loading
    const filter = (e) => {
      const keyword = e.target.value;
        if (keyword !== '') {
            const filteredData = posts.filter((post) => {
                return Object.values(post)
                .join('')
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
            })
            setFilteredResults(filteredData)
        } else {
          setFilteredResults(posts)
        }
        setSearchInput(keyword);
    }
  return (
    <div className="posts">
      <div className="postsContainer">
      <div className="postsSearchContainer">
            <div className="postsSearch">
                  <div class="postsSearchIconContainer">
                      <SearchIcon class="w-5 h-5" />
                  </div>
                    <input type="text"
                    className="postsSearchInput"
                    placeholder=“search”
                    name="postsSearchText"
                    id="postsSearchText"
                    onChange={filter}
                    />
              </div>
              {/* ENDS OF POSTSSEARCHCONTAINER */}
      </div>
      {/* ENDS OF POSTSSEARCH */}
    <div className="postsBoxContainer">
      <div className="postsBox">
      {isLoading ? (
          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <CircularProgress />
          </Box>
      ) : (
        filteredResults.length > 0 ? (
          filteredResults.map((filteredPosts) => (
            <Post post={filteredPosts} />
          ))
          ) : (posts.map((post) => (
            <Post isPostsLoading={isPostsLoading} post={post} />
          )) )
        )
        }
      </div>
      </div>
      {/* ENDS OF POSTSBOX */}
      </div>
      {/* ENDS OF POSTCONTAINER */}
    </div>
    //ENDS OF POSTS

  );
};
```

**`AllPosts.jsx`** (Here Where I'm using the api to fetch all the posts and using the boolean to know if it's loaded or not)

```
export default function AllPosts() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const [isPostsLoading, setIsPostsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("/posts" + search);
      setPosts(res.data);
      setIsPostsLoading(false);
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, [search]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="posts">
        {/* <Header /> */}
        <div className="header">
        <div className="headerTitle">
            <span className="headerTitleLg">المقالات</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div className="postsContent">
        <Posts posts={posts} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The question is how to pass booleans as props to the other components

Comment: I don't understand what's your issue. How to pass boolean as props? Just like any other props.

Comment: Yes, the issue is the skeleton is not showing on my component